# 'No module named requests' even if I installed requests with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to test if requests module has been well installed. But I'm getting the following error :

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

when trying to run the following test script:

```
import requests
print 'test'
```

But I have installed requests with pip, and `pip list` command gives the following result :

```
MBPdeMacBook2:~ macbookpro$ pip list
arrow (0.7.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
classifier (1.6.5)
coursera-dl (0.6.1)
Django (1.8.6)
html5lib (1.0b8)
keyring (9.0)
lxml (3.6.0)
Pillow (3.4.2)
pip (8.0.2)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
requests (2.14.2)
setuptools (19.4)
six (1.10.0)
urllib3 (1.16)
vboxapi (1.0)
virtualenv (13.1.2)
wheel (0.26.0)
```

Why requests isn't being imported ?

EDIT :

```
MBPdeMacBook2:~ macbookpro$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
MBPdeMacBook2:~ macbookpro$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
MBPdeMacBook2:~ macbookpro$ python --version
Python 2.7.11
MBPdeMacBook2:~ macbookpro$ pip --version
pip 8.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Are you sure the pip environment is the same as the python one? Do `which pip` and `which python`. It could be you are installing for Python3 and running with Python27

Comment: @OptimusCrime see my edit

Comment: Can you also run `python --version` and `pip --version`?

Comment: @OptimusCrime see my edit please

Comment: `pip` is not pointing to the same environment as your `python`. You need to look at your `PATH` variable... see if you have `pip` installed for your `python`, e.g. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip` or (`pip2`, `pip2.7`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but the paths from `which python` and `which pip` may indicate that you have two versions installed. The Python version being the old one that was shipped with OS X, and another version.

I would advice you to install Python27 (or even better Python3) from brew.

You can install brew [with a single command](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starting/install/osx/), and another one for installing Python27/3. When this is done you set the `PATH` variable in your shell rc file and you should be good to go.

I have Python27 installed (via brew) and my (working environment) reports the following paths:

```
which python: /usr/local/bin/python
which pip: /usr/local/bin/pip
```

And

```
python --version: 2.7.15
pip --version: pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python2.7)
```

Comment: How can I edit the Path so python point to the version shipped with OSX ?

Comment: @mounaim It is exampled in the link I provided. You edit the file `~/.profile` and insert `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`

Answer (score 12):

In general, you should get into the habit of working in a `virtualenv`. I find the documentation [here](https://python-guide-cn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html) to be helpful.

If you install all of your dependencies within the virtual environment, you'll be (mostly) sure that you are installing those deps. in the same environment that you're running the jobs in.

For your case,  on the command line go to the directory where your code lives and run

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv my_project
source my_project/bin/activate
```

Now that the virtualenv is active you can

```
pip install requests
```

Only what is installed in the virtualenv will be available. This will keep your system clean. Each project should get its own virtualenv, meaning only the dependencies needed for each project will be available to them. This way you could, say, have version 1 of some dependency installed for one project and version 2 for another. They won't come into conflict.

After you have installed all the dependencies, run

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To get a list of all the dependencies for the project saved. Next time you need to install these, you simply run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Once you are done working in the virtualenv, run

```
deactivate
```

Comment: I did the whole `pip freeze > requirements.txt` from within a virtualenv, and then, in another folder, copied over `requirements.txt`, created a new virtualenv, ran `source env/bin/activate` then `pip install -r requiremnts.txt` and got the error `no module named requests`. But, running `pip install requests` again (even though it *was* in the requirements.txt file all along) fixed the issue. Weird but that's what happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, to check that, I first checked if requests library was installed on my system or not.

Run these commands on your terminal inside the virtual environment in which you working

```
$ python
```

Then the python command line opens, then run

```
>>> import requests
```

After this if you get an ImportError saying, No module named requests, then it means the dependency has not been installed properly. If there is no such error, then it means the dependency is installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur for example if pip is actually pip3 and python is actually python2.7.
In your case the which pip and which python eliminate this possibility but it just happened to me.

The solution was to do pip2 instead of pip; if the situation was reversed you can use pip3.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go inside your virtual environment and run below commands:

1). pip install --user pipenv
2). pipenv install requests

after executing the above commands **cd** to your app folder inside the virtual environment and just run it. Hopefully now it will run.

Reference link: https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/pt_BR/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html#make-sure-you-ve-got-python-pip